# Is passing an argument of a method to another method a bad practice?

Tags: methods, arguments, standards

I have the following method:

```
public myMethod(argument1)
{
  int myVariable = myMethod2(argument1)
  ...
}
```

Is it bad practice to pass an argument from one method right into another one?  I am aware alternatives exist, (such as I could use a static variable), but for the sake of learning and argument, say that I can't.

Comment: It's not a bad practice, in fact in most cases I'd say it's a good practice, in contrast to relying on external state.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where object oriented programming could become useful. For instance you could define a class like this.

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
       int myArgument;

    public:
       myMethod()
       {
          myvariable = myMethod2();  //now you don't need to worry 
                                       about passing in the redundant argument
       }
       myMethod2()
       {
          return myArgument*2;
       }

};
```

For the sake of your example, the class is probably overkill for this application, so whether or not this matter's is up to you. If you start to realize you are passing around the same parameter between tons of related functions, that is where the idea of encapsulating the data in an object becomes valuable (assuming you are using a language that supports OOP like C++).